# How to load asp.net webpages faster using .htaccess

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, .htaccess

How to load asp.net webpages faster using .htaccess..

what was the coding for .htaccess so that the webpages loads faster ..i have hosted my site on ...ixwebhosting. ..

Comment: .htaccess to the rescue of badly written pages too?

Comment: Are you running this on Mono? .htaccess files contain configuration settings for the Apache web server.

Comment: You cannot magically make bad code run faster.

Answer (score 0):

The `.htaccess` file is used by web servers like Apache and IIS will not use that file. In general you configure IIS using files like `web.config`.